# bash if-else statement not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script in which I check the execution codes (0 assign to **SUCCESS** and 1 assign to **FAILURE**). I am using a if-else statement to check whether the execution code is 0 or 1.

If it is 0 I want to assign the text **SUCCESS** to a variable RESULT.
else assign the text **FAILURE** to a variable RESULT.

Note: I need to use RESULT somewhere else.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eo pipefail
RESULT="SUCCESS"
if [ "${STATUS}" != "0" ]; then
  RESULT="FAILURE"
else
  RESULT="SUCCESS"
fi
   
cat "${STATUS}"
echo
echo ${RESULT}
```

However, it looks like doesn't matter what whether I send in a 0 or 1 I keep getting FAILURE for result. Here is the output:

```
[e2e-st] 0
[e2e-st] 
[e2e-st] FAILURE
```

I expect to get 0 **SUCCESS**, instead I get 0 **FAILURE**.

Any tips on what am I doing wrong or what I could do differently?

---

After getting help and solution here:

```
    - name: STATUS
      value: $(steps.step-run-script.exitCode.path)
  script: |
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    set -eo pipefail

    echo "STATUS=$STATUS"
    ls -l "$STATUS"
    STATUSVALUE=$(cat "$STATUS")
    echo ${STATUSVALUE}

    if [ "$STATUSVALUE" -eq 0 ]; then
      echo ok
      RESULT="SUCCESS"
      echo ${STATUSVALUE}
      echo ${RESULT}
    else
      echo failed...
      RESULT="FAILURE"
      echo ${STATUSVALUE}
      echo ${RESULT}
    fi
```

And this is what I get:

```
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] STATUS=/tekton/steps/step-run-script/exitCode
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] -rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1002340000 1 Mar 10 14:03 /tekton/steps/step-run-script/exitCode
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] 0
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] ok
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] 0
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] SUCCESS
```

and another run where my tests fail:

```
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] STATUS=/tekton/steps/step-run-script/exitCode
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] -rw-r--r--. 1 1000 1002340000 1 Mar 10 14:05 /tekton/steps/step-run-script/exitCode
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] 1
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] failed...
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] 1
[e2e-st : send-test-report-and-status-to-jira-comment] FAILURE
```

Thank you so much for the help!
Everything works as expected.

Comment: How exactly do you "_send in a 0 or 1_"?

Comment: Your sample code doesn't print `[e2e-st]`. What does this represent and where does it come from?

Comment: Can you say something about the `STATUS` variable? You seem to want to test its value for `0`, but you also use it as a filename with `cat` (do you have files called `0` and `1`?)  The code never assigns a value to the variable.  As roaima said, it's also unclear what produces the output that you quote.

Comment: @roaima this from OpenShift Tekton pipeline.
        - name: STATUS
          value: $(steps.step-run-script.exitCode.path)
      script: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        set -eo pipefail
...
And [e2e-st] is the prompt of my my pipeline terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda
The STATUS is defined and we get the value the following way:
```
- name: STATUS 
value: $(steps.step-run-script.exitCode.path) 
script: | 
#!/usr/bin/env bash set -eo pipefail
```
And I am getting the correct execution codes using cat "${STATUS}" just the text assign to the variable RESULT is not working.

Comment: As you compare numbers use `-ne` instead of `!=`

Comment: What do you mean by "I am getting the correct execution codes"? Your command `cat "${STATUS}"` indicates that you are using `$STATUS` as a filename, and your output indicates that the contents of that file is the single character `0`.  It does not say anything about what value `$STATUS` is (it could be `1` or `ok` or `failed` on whatever).

Comment: When I copy and paste your script to my local system and run it with `STATUS=0 bash -x ./script` I see `RESULT` being assigned the value `SUCCESS` (twice), and then the script dies because it can't open the file called `0` (the value of `$STATUS`).  Giving `STATUS` the name of an existing file, like `/etc/passwd`, I see `RESULT` first being assigned the value `SUCCESS` and then `FAILURE` before the contents of the file is outputted to the terminal and the string `FAILURE` is printed.

Comment: @fatkobra please don't put updates in the comments. They're difficult to follow and easy to miss. Instead, please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/739304/edit) to add the information as if you'd included it originally.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys!
Kudos to: @ilkkachu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about OpenShift or Tekton, the word "path" in "steps.step-run-script.exitCode.path" appears to indicate a filename, as does the fact that `cat $STATUS` works.

Put something like

```
echo "STATUS=$STATUS"
ls -l "$STATUS"
```

in the script to see what the value of the variable `$STATUS` is, and to see the file.

The contents of the file don't automatically get copied in a variable holding the *name* of the file, so you need to use e.g. `cat` to read it, as you do later in the script. E.g.

```
STATUSVALUE=$(cat "$STATUS")
if [ "$STATUSVALUE" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ok
else
    echo failed...
fi
```

If you can, you might also consider renaming the variable, something like `STATUSFILE` might be more descriptive.